# Passive UMTS antenna

Tags: wireless, antenna

I'm the owner of an old 2nd world war bunker. To imagine it, a short overview: Imagine they drilled 50 meters into a mountain, then drilled out a big hall, in which they built a regular building. It has an emergency exit, like a chimney.

I'm evaluating a system to get 3G inside. So the easiest way to do that is by putting a yagi antenna at the end of the chimney-exit. The other end will be in the room inside.

Do I need to use a GSM repeater or is yagi-antenna/20mcalbe/inhouse-antenna enough for a standard smartphone to connect to the outside world.

In other words, is it working just with antenna and cable without a repeater?

Answer (score 2):

Neat problem.

I think you'll need the GSM repeater.  Considering they are not that expensive compared to the cost of other equipment you'll need, it's probably your best bet.

The geology is going to have some impact.  If you happen to be surrounded by a lot of metal, you're in a big Faraday cage.  If you happen to be surrounded by radioactive material, that will interfere.  (Many stone buildings give off significant amounts of radiation.)  It's quite possible that you will run into some strange problems.  If getting it right quickly was a concern, I'd hire a professional to bring in test equipment and determine what's feasible.